# Network not connected on android emulator (macOS)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

Hi guys I'm trying to build a voice recognition app using Android Studio and running it on my emulator. It says network is not connected when I tried to use the voice recognition, but I can use google on the emulator perfectly fine which was weird.

I've tried changing my DNS, and also have tried adb kill-server and adb start-server, but I still have the same problem.
I've also made my friend who uses windows pc to try running the code and it seems to work. So I'm sure this is a Mac problem but I just can't figure it out.

[Screenshot of the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDjbD.png)

Comment: It looks like your code contained a network call.